# OpenOPC using Python

Tags: python, ole, opc, open-opc

I am trying to do some stuff with siemens PLC using OPENOPC using python. I am wondering how I will get OPC server that I can communicate using PYOPC. Is there any open OPC server available or am I not understanding some of the key concepts here? Since I am a newbie, I hope to get some down-to-earth suggestions.

Comment: me to. Im doing the EXACT same. how far are you now?

Comment: I am just starting out! Please let me know about your progress and I if I came first, I will let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install some tryout opc servers. google opc simulation. The python OpenOPC client is what i try to use.

My problems was that I did not have a plc on my desk. You need a plc on your desk connected to your actual siemens s7 engineering station to have the siemens opc server show the tags in the plc.

Answer (score 1):

I use a Kepware OPC that is running in demo mode to connect to real PLC hardware. The only issue is that I must restart the computer every two hours to reset the demo license.

For simulations I use [the Matrikon OPC simulation server](https://www.matrikonopc.com/downloads/178/index.aspx)